# With two custom post types, how to make one a child of the other in the admin menu?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

Been following [Justin Tadlock](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/41192/justin-tadlock)'s nice clear [tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2013/10/07/post-relationships-parent-to-child) on how to have one custom post type act as a dropdown for another in the admin edit screen.

His example is of a restaurant CPT needing a dropdown to a neighbourhood CPT (btw, as the author points out in the comments, the reason not to just use a taxonomy is that the neighbourhood could have a bunch of custom fields not catered for by the built in taxonomy).

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

The tutorial code works perfectly on our site.

My question is, to keep the admin menu clean it would be nice to have everything sit under one root entry like so:

```
Places
 - Add New
 - Neighbourhoods
```

I only know how to add a root level CPT. So mine looks like this:

```
Places
  - Add New
Neighbourhoods
  - Add New
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `register_post_type` call, use the argument `show_in_menu`:

```
register_post_type(
    'neighbourhood',
    array(
        'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=place',
        // other args
    )
);
```

Comment: tried it, it works !